# Are angular 2 component getters reevaluated after each change?

Tags: angular, typescript

if not what are the benifits of using getters over attributes initialized using ngOnInit ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, getters are reevaluated every time Angular runs change detection, the same as with simple fields.

Comment: how to tell angular to stop observing it because that it will never change after first rendering (one time binding) for better performance

Comment: There is no one-time-binding in Angular2. If your getter does non-tivial computation, it would be better to assign the value to a field and bind to this field instead of using a getter. Angular2 is quite efficient with detecting changes for fields. To reduce the number of times change detection is run for a component, you can switch to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on a per component basis.